How to use solidity events in react useEffect?
I want to subscribe to a solidity event listener, but in useEffect called two times during render. How to unsubscribe from events or how to handle it?
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('ADD');

  counterContract.events.Increment().on('data', (event) => ReadContractValue());
  counterContract.events.Decrement().on('data', (event) => ReadContractValue());
  return () => {
    console.log('REMOVE');
    counterContract.events.Decrement().unsubscribe();
    counterContract.events.Increment().removeAllListeners();
  };
}, []);

It writes:
ADD
REMOVE
ADD

But both event listener is still subscribed.

You should get the subscription object before calling .on(), as that object contains the unsubscribe function you need to call when the component gets unmounted:
const isSubscribedRef = useRef(false);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isSubscribedRef.current) return;

  isSubscribedRef.current = true;

  const incrementSubscription = counterContract.events.Increment();
  const decrementSubscription = counterContract.events.Decrement();

  incrementSubscription.on('data', (event) => ReadContractValue());
  decrementSubscription.on('data', (event) => ReadContractValue());

  return () => {
    incrementSubscription.unsubscribe();
    decrementSubscription.unsubscribe();
  };
}, []);

See Mastering Events Subscriptions in Web3.js' docs.
On the other hand, you useEffect() might be running twice if your are using React 18 in dev mode with React.StrictMode, as it will mount your components twice, as explained in React's 18 upgrade post.
I've added a ref to prevent that, but you should not use/need it, as your component should just work as expected after remounting.
